# Preferred method to select control in javascript?

Tags: javascript

When looking at tutorials of javascript I often see someting like this

```
function func(){
   var e = document.getElementById('id');
   e.value = true;   
}
```

I was wondering if there is a difference between that and say this

```
function func(){
   document.getElementById('id').value = true;  
}
```

Comment: both means the same thing. but using `document.getElementById('id').value = true;` is recommended if you have to perform single operation on the selected object.

Comment: No difference. It probably doesn't really matter in terms of performance since it's pretty fast anyway.

Comment: @yiiframe Recommended by *who*?

Comment: if you are using once then method 2 is preffered. If want to use in a more than say 100 line of code of a function then method 1 is preffered in stead of writing all just the variable assigned can be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a difference if it is used correctly. In the simple example you posted it does not matter, however usually you have a much more complex app where caching selectors is important:

```
// initialization code, cache selectors
var e = document.getElementById('id');

// in a deeply nested function called in a loop many times
function x() {
    e.value = true;
}
```

In this case it would be very poor performance to continuously do the lookup so caching makes a big difference. Here is [jsperf example](http://jsperf.com/http-jsperf-com-meldville-dom) showing the performance benefits.

Comment: If you have deeply nested functions farting around with a variable called `e`, performance is the least of your issues.  :)

Comment: @cHao, check out the jsperf, number don't lie. If you've ever worked on a computationally intensive app, especially on mobile browsers, these low hanging fruits make a big difference to the user.

Comment: If the app is actually computationally intensive, it's spending far more time computing than messing with the DOM anyway.  So the jsperf numbers basically *do* lie.

Comment: So what's your advice? Avoid performance improvements just because you have too much other computation? What are you getting at?

Comment: Optimize for readability first, is what i'm getting at.  Don't go declaring variables a mile away from where they're actually used, just cause a microbenchmark says it's faster.  *If* it makes a significant difference in your specific case, then and only then *might* it be worth the net loss in maintainability.

Comment: Readability is certainly important. However in this case it's win win especially if you have good accessors defined. In fact, frameworks like jQuery do this for you all the time behind the scenes.

Comment: Fortunately, i don't have to maintain jQuery.  :P  But even if they do it, they have reason to care -- their whole business is messing around with the DOM.  Most apps are not jQuery, though, and will not see a difference worth sacrificing readability for.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is difference as such.

But I'll prefer first one for these reasons:-

1. Might we have to perform more than one operation on the object.
2. If the code is like below

   ```
   document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].textContent = true;
   ```

   in this case I would like to break this in two statements like bellow

   ```
   var div = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];
   div.textContent = true
   ```

   It's a lot more readable than previous one.